# Clicking on image does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a click event for an image using jQuery but I fail every time I try.

First I have a div:

```
<div id="price-holder"></div>
```

then I am using jQuery to insert this HTML by using the following:

```
$("#price-menu li:nth-child(2)").click(function() { 
    var pregHTML = $("#cakesmash-price").html();
    $("#price-holder").html(pregHTML);
});
```

However, using this HTML doesn't work

```
<div id="cakesmash-price" style="display:none">
   <img  id="cake" src="images/order.png" height="32px" onclick="pregbasic(this);">
</div>
```

I tried to use the attribute `onclick` for the image and also tried using jQuery's selector with the ID like so

```
$("#cake").click(function(){

})
```

but both didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is disjointed and incomplete. Please organize it and include the list markup.

Comment: Works here. http://jsfiddle.net/kd62H/. Theres something wrong with your selector. Please post your full HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This assumes that the element is actually being added to the page.*

I am betting you are adding the click event before you add the element to the page meaning the selector did not find anything so it did not add the event.

Either add the event after you add the element or use event delegation.

```
$("#price-holder").html(pregHTML);
$("#cake").click(function(){

});
```

or

```
$("#price-holder").on("click", "#cake", function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error could be due to your choice of selectors "#price-menu li:nth-child(2)". Try using the JS .children and .eq selectors. Also if your code was added dynamically consider using the .on() event handler rather than the .click().

Answer (score -1):

Just start with the DOM you actually want, without using jQuery to do this:

```
<div id="price-holder">
    <div id="cakesmash-price" style="display:none">
        <img  id="cake" src="images/order.png" height="32px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can just add you click handler on #cake:

```
$('#cake').on('click', function (event) {
    // your logic goes here
});
```

Comment: missed the inline script in your example; removed the onclick on the image.